# Acer Chromebook 11 technology

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, worksheet-function, operating-systems

Most people know that Acer Chromebook 11s are cheap and are more experimental than some other Chromebooks (ASUS, Samsung, etc.)but I have a question if there is anyone that knows how to install Microsoft's Windows 10 and it's operating system via terminal and if not what USB stick is best?

Comment: Have you verified that this device meets the minimum requirements for Windows 10?  We will be unable to recommend specific hardware to accomplish what you want.  **It is up to you to select the flash storage device you want to use.**  Why do you want to install Windows over a terminal connection, the closest to doing that would be booting to WinPE, but the device would have to support PXE which I doubt it does.

Comment: My Acer Chromebook 11 is compatible with seaBIOS though...

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I install Windows 10 on a Chromebook 11?

First check [Windows 8.1 or 10 on the chromebooks](https://coolstar.org/chromebook/windows.html) to see if it is possible and the appropriate drivers are available.

Note: 4 GB of RAM and 64 GB or higher SSD Recommended

You are in luck as the Chromebook 11 seems to be good to go:

[image]

Next follow the instructions at [How to Install Windows on a Chromebook](https://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/) but note the following warning:

> This isn’t officially supported. To do this, you’ll have to install a
>   replacement BIOS for your Chromebook (technically it’s a UEFI
>   firmware, which is the modern replacement to the traditional BIOS).
>   This will allow you to boot and install Windows. The replacement BIOS
>   can only be installed on Chromebook models that it supports, so you
>   can’t do this on every model of Chromebook.
>
> You’ll need some additional hardware as well. You’ll need a USB
>   keyboard and mouse just to install Windows, because your Chromebook’s
>   built-in keyboard and mouse won’t work in the installer. And you’ll
>   need a PC running Windows to create the USB installation media for
>   your Chromebook.
>
> Even after you install Windows, you won’t be out of the woods. Windows
>   doesn’t ship with hardware drivers for various pieces of hardware,
>   like the touchpads incorporated into many Chromebooks (which makes
>   sense, since Chromebook manufacturers never bothered creating Windows
>   drivers for these components). If you’re lucky, you’ll find
>   third-party drivers that were hacked together to give Windows support
>   for these components.
>
> This will also, obviously, wipe your Chromebook, so make sure you
>   don’t have anything important stored on it. (You shouldn’t, as Chrome
>   OS usually syncs your data with Google.)

There are complete instructions with screenshots at [How to Install Windows on a Chromebook](https://www.howtogeek.com/278953/how-to-install-windows-on-a-chromebook/) which unfortunately too long to reproduce here.

Comment: Isn't it seaBIOS?

Comment: @Jeffthedeveloper No idea ...